# Print targets that need to be remade

Tags: makefile

I need to see the list of targets (files) that would be remade if I run *make* command for specific target. I guess this can be done by parsing debug output of *make* utility.

Answer (score 0):

To list the targets that would be remade, you can run the following command:

```
make -dn MAKE=: your_target | sed -rn "s/^ *Must remake target '(.*)'\.$/\1/p"
```

If you remove `MAKE=:` then targets for sub-makes will be printed too.

Unfortunately some files that are imported to your Makefile using the `include` directive will be listed too. They can be [filtered out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299465/152606) using the following shell script (`list-targs`):

```
#!/bin/sh -e

dbg="`make -dn "$@"`"
all="`echo -n "$dbg" | sed -rn "s/^ *Must remake target '(.+)'\.$/\1/p"`"
mks="`echo -n "$dbg" | sed -rn "s/^ *Reading makefile '([^']+)'.*$/\1/p"`"
echo -n "$all" | grep -vxF "$mks"
```

Now you can see the targets to remake using this command:

```
list-targs MAKE=: your_target
```

If you need list all dependencies (not only those that are to be remade), see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/574590/152606).